# faster fopen or file_get_contents?

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents

i am running multiple websites with high traffic , as a requirement , all images are downloaded via `image.php?id=IMAGE_ID_HERE` . 
If you ever done that before , you know that that file will be reading the file image and echoing it to the browser with special headers .

My problem is , the load on the server is very high (150-200) and TOP command shows multiple instances of image.php , so image.php is running slow !

the problem probably is `fopen` loading the image to the memory before sending it to the client. How to read a file and pass it through directly?

Thank you guys

---

**UPDATE**

After you optimized the code, used caching wherever possible, do create a CDN . couple of servers, sync methods, load balancers and no need to worry about requests anymore :)

Comment: What's wrong with `file_get_contents`? Or why don't you just use `fphassthru` or `readfile`? And if this is just about custom headers, consider using `mod_cern_meta` or `mod_headers`.

Comment: For all questions asking whether fnA() or fnB() is faster: just profile your code. it will give you the answer and chances are you will find that something else is slowing you down.

Comment: @Gordon , assuming you have checked all of the code , optimized everything , got rid of other things till nothing happened ?

Comment: Why not implement the special headers in Apache or Nginx conf files and serve the images right from files? No solution touching the PHP processor would mach it.

Comment: I don't think you can appreciably increase your speed changing `fopen` to `file_get_contents`, I think you should pay attention to caching and architecture changes maybe..

Comment: @RonanDejhero Not sure what you are trying to say but in any case profiling is the way to go instead of asking for a synthetic a() vs b().

Comment: Might be on the sideline, but using js and ajax, you can download the pictures in the background, so the user don't have to wait for all of them to download. Common trick on pages with huge and detailed pictures.

Comment: @Optimus that's completely unrelated to the problem

Comment: @OptimusCrime ... am more worried about the server load that is caused of the image.php

Comment: @RonanDejhero ; then you might have to rethink the idea with image.php, can't you use any other solutions?

Comment: @OptimusCrime limited by requirements . i can just edit the code inside of iamge.php

Comment: @Gordon he has a problem. Like many others he has no clue where it is or even how to phrase it, so, he is asking quite pointless question, but *the problem* can be seen behind it.

Comment: @Gordon after finding the problem , the problem was the slow speed of fopen , the while loop for reading the file , then the echo of the contents (echoing takes more time than u think , in online algorithm tests using echo might give you 25% less mark) . ill be trying `readfile`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

fopen and file_get_contents are nearly equivalent

to speed up with consistence the page load you can use

http://www.php.net/fpassthru

or, even better

http://www.php.net/readfile

with those functions, content of file is printed directly, byte per byte

as opposed to file_get_contents, for example, where you store the whole data inside a variable

```
$var = file_get_contents();
```

so, to make these work correctly you will need to disable output buffering (otherwise it would make readfile() pointless) in the page that serves the images

hope this helps!

Comment: Let me guess you don't have a top populated with image.php, nor had it ever.

Comment: ill try that , hope the load drops :)

Comment: @RonanDejhero yes, do not use fopen or file_get_contents, try to use fpassthru for a week and monitor the server load

Comment: am doing that , the load will drop in  minute

Comment: nopaste the image.php code, I want to listen the point of view of col.shrapnel

Comment: if you still having issues with serverload after using fpassthru and you are able to install apache modules, you can try mod_xsendfile see this link for more info http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/03/06/sending-files-better-apache-mod_xsendfile-and-php/

Comment: with `file_get_contents()` you don't _have_ to store the contents in a variable, for example when used as such: `file_put_contents('images/', file_get_contents($imgURL));`

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you cache the image content with apc ?

```
if(!apc_exists('img_'.$id)){
    apc_store('img_'.$id,file_get_content(...));
}

echo apc_fetch('img_'.$id);
```

this way image content will not be read from your disk more than once.

Comment: apc is hard to setup correctly. but it could be a good solution!

Comment: Well if the website as lots of hits than I/O on disk is high due to concurent file_get_contents, storing the content in ram would get rid of that

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel reading from Memory is faster than reading from Disk

Comment: there is not a sign of the I/O peak in the question. Go figure. It clearly says that it's CPU utilization above the limits.

Comment: In my experience lots of I/O is never good for load performance. If this guy has a load of 200 on this particular script than he has high IO because of the way the file are served. I'm not saying it will fix his issues but It's worth a shot IMO.

Comment: if you're getting like 5000 image requests/second , that would be a problem for the memory if APC is memory-based cache !!! specially if you have thousands of images !!!

Comment: I believe the issue is not the number of requests / seconds but more the size of all the images, you could also couple that with a RoundRobin solution. I know facebook uses memcache to cache some of their profile image so there is a reason why...

Comment: with the 5000 images /second ... i meant deferent images not the same , otherwise i would have cached them