# How do I read a file from a destination to variable?

Tags: php

I am trying to read a file's content, while doing something like this

```
$con="HDdeltin";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/HDdeltin/Users/$con", "r");
echo $fp;
```

It doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: fopen() returns a resource ID, not content.

Comment: Start with [the docs on `fopen()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). It returns a file handle from which you must `fread()` or `fgets()`. More likely, you wan t something simpler like [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast solution :

```
file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/HDdeltin/Users/HDdeltin");
```

Use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), and you can prevent bad url with [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

```
$con = "HDdeltin";
$path = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/HDdeltin/Users/$con");
echo file_get_contents($path);
```

To get current root, you can also use :

- [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) function.
- `dirname(__FILE__)`, you can get [more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

See more :

- [faster fopen or file_get_contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806561/faster-fopen-or-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` return a resource, not the text

Use `file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/HDdeltin/Users/$con")` instead

Answer (score 0):

you can read by using this function

```
echo file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/HDdeltin/Users/$con");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to use file_get_contents. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Here is the example they provide:

```
// Read 14 characters starting from the 21st character
$section = file_get_contents('./people.txt', NULL, NULL, 20, 14);
var_dump($section);
```

So you will likely need to use

```
$fp = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/HDdeltin/Users/$con", true);
echo $fp;
```

There are some differences between PHP versions it seems

```
<?php
// <= PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', true);
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```

So be sure to check out the first link provided.